# How does web-mode recognize the php code or html code

Tags: web-mode, php-mode

It looks a quite magic that the web-mode could mix with php mode.
A major mode could contain another major mode. This seems amazing.

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . php-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.blade\\.php\\'" . web-mode))
```

If I have a file named "portal.blade.php",  how does web-mode recognize the internal php code?

Comment: One question per customer . . . consider editing to frame just one (1) specific question.  Consider also specifying what is meant by "recognize the internal php code" -- i.e., what is it that the original poster expects to see happen?  Has the original poster tried using the library yet --- and if so, what happened and why is it now a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert in this, but taking a quick look at the code I say it's regular expressions. Web-mode seems to use regexes to search for `<?|<?php` tags, then it knows what comes further is php code. The same goes for html, asp, javascript and other languages. I think you should look at the code yourself (`M-x describe-function web-mode`). And if you're really interested, you could try writing a simple major mode to better understand how major modes work, then you should be able to know better what web-mode does under the hood.